# How to merge only remote changes in vimdiff?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, vimdiff

After forking a Github repository I performed some changes in it. This was quite some time back, now the upstream branch is well ahead. Thus I wanted to merge those remote changes into my forked repo.

I hit upon a merge conflict in one file only. I went ahead and ran `vimdiff` as the `mergetool` to sort these things out. 
I only want to **merge in the remote changes** and discard the local ones.

But there are *too* many conflicting hunks in that file. Selecting changes to merge one by one is tedious to say the least.

- Is there a shortcut to `:diffget RE` on all the conflicts in that file?
- Maybe there is a method to select only a branches diff while discarding the other one in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merging in git has two options that can default to using remote changes (theirs) or local changes (ours).

If you want to resolve conflicts only to the remote changes in a merge you would do the following:

```
git merge -Xtheirs <branch>
```

If you want to resolve conflicts only to the local changes in a merge you would do the following:

```
git merge -Xours <branch>
```

You can find more about advance merging strategies from the [git advanced merging documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging).

Answer (score 12):

Using Vims global select you can replace all diffs with either LOCAL, BASE or REMOTE

1. Go to first line in file

> ```
> :1
> ```

2. Go into visual mode

> ```
>  <Shift>-V
> ```

3. Go to bottom of file, and select all lines

> ```
> G
> ```

4. Issue the diffget command on all lines

> ```
> :diffget REMOTE
> ```

Comment: for those who want to cut out 6 keystrokes, `:diffg RE` is sufficent for the last command. For those who want only local changes,  use `:diffget LOCAL` or `difg LO`

Comment: I had to use ":diffget 3" or it said "More than one match for RE". not sure exactly why, but buffer 3 referred to my remote branch (top right buffer)